# How to solve a QCQP where constraints are balls?

Tags: algorithms, convex-optimization, closed-form, qcqp, proximal-operators

I want to solve the following optimization problem in variables $\theta_1, \theta_2, \dots, \theta_K$

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    & \underset{\theta}{\text{minimize}}
    & & \sum_{k=1}^{K} \|g_k - \theta_k\|_2^2 \\
    & \text{subject to}
    & & \| \theta_m - \theta_l \|_2^2 \leq \| x_m - x_l \|_2^2 , \quad 1 \leq m < l \leq K,
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $x_i$ and $g_i$ are constants and $\| \cdot \|_2$ denotes the Euclidean norm.

Is there any closed-form for arbitrary $K$? Or an appropriate first-order iterative method which yields an approximate solution?

Comment: Are the $\theta$ values variables being optimized over or constants?

Comment: $\theta_i$ are the variables of the optimization problem; $g_i$ and $x_i$ are constants.

Comment: This is a convex quadratically constrained QP that is easily solvable by iterative methods.  For example, it's easy to implement in CVX.  I don't think you'll get a closed form solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @BrianBorchers. Actually, I've already used CVX to solve it but I am particularly interested in first-order iterative methods due to the size of the problem